# Android Non Instrumented test in a library failing when ran via command line ./gradlew clean {library_name}:testDebugUnitTest

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, kotlin, android-testing

I know the issue but I do not know what commands to use to possibly fix it.

The issue is there are some dependencies in the Library that are compileOnly. I could fix this by adding all the compileOnly as a testImplementation in the library but I was hoping not to do that.

Is there a way to possibly build the app and compile then run the library tests?

I already tried ./gradlew clean build {library_name}:testDebugUnitTest

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I was using compileOnly for some dependencies that the tests needed. Updating those to implementation fixes the issue.